# union multiple tables and group with aggregation (SQlite)

Tags: sqlite, group-by, union

I have such kind of a data:

`table1`

```
id | part  | price
1  | ox900 | 100
2  | ox980 | 200
```

and

`table2`

```
id | part  | price
1  | ox560 | 560
2  | ox980 | 120
```

as result I want to get such schema:

```
id | part  | priceTable1 | priceTable2 | minPrice
1  | ox900 | 100         |             | 100
1  | ox980 | 200         | 120         | 120
1  | ox560 |             | 560         | 560
```

to simplify it can be without `minPrice` column...

now I have such query:

```
SELECT  *
FROM (select part, price from supportContacts
union all
select part, price from supportContacts2)
group by part
```

but it's not exactly what I want to achieve.

Is it possible somehow to do, what I've described above?

Also a fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/f7401/7/0

Comment: Do an outer join instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not support full outer joins, so get a list of all parts first, and then look up their prices with left outer joins:

```
SELECT part,
       table1.price AS priceTable1,
       table2.price AS priceTable2,
       min(ifnull(table1.price, 'inf'),
           ifnull(table2.price, 'inf')) AS minPrice
FROM (SELECT part FROM table1
      UNION
      SELECT part FROM table2)
LEFT JOIN table1 USING (part)
LEFT JOIN table2 USING (part);
```

([fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/f7401/5))

Comment: a good idea... but as min i can have a null there - it's not right :)

Comment: Oops, the non-aggregated `min()` does not ignore NULLs …

Comment: buy the way, if i will have 1,2,3..n more same tables, it's the same, right?

Comment: Yes. (But it would be bad database design to have many such tables.)

Comment: by the way, why are you using `AS priceTable1` ?

Comment: Because you asked for this column name in the output.

Comment: by the way... is there any way to skip non-existing values in first table? soL I mean, for example, if in second row such part doesn't exists - skip this in result output, and only display all existing in first table?
`intersect` right?

Comment: That would be a different question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47261754/sqlite3-how-to-select-rows-presented-only-in-first-table-with-other-table-joi here it is :)