# sqlite3: how to select row's presented only in first table (with other table join)

Tags: sql, sqlite, union

I have such structure:

`mainTable`

```
article | brand      | price
ocm10   | someBrand1 | 100
ocm20   | someBrand1 | 200
ocm30   | someBrand2 | 300
```

`secondTable`

```
article | brand      | price
ocm30   | someBrand1 | 320
ocm10   | someBrand1 | 120
```

`thirdTable`

```
article | brand      | price
ocm20   | someBrand1 | 230
ocm40   | someBrand1 | 430
ocm50   | someBrand3 | 530
```

and right now i have such query:

```
SELECT article,
       mainTable.brand AS priceBrand,
       mainTable.price AS priceTableMain,
       secondTable.price AS priceTableSecond,
       thirdTable.price AS priceTableThird,
       min(ifnull(mainTable.price, 'inf'),
           ifnull(secondTable.price, 'inf'),
           ifnull(thirdTable.price, 'inf')) AS minPrice
FROM (SELECT article FROM mainTable
      UNION
      SELECT article FROM secondTable
      UNION
      SELECT article FROM thirdTable)
LEFT JOIN mainTable USING (article)
LEFT JOIN secondTable USING (article)
LEFT JOIN thirdTable USING (article);
```

as result I want to see:

```
article | brand      | priceMainTable | priceSecond | priceThird | minPrice
ocm10   | someBrand1 | 100            |   null      | null       | 100
ocm20   | someBrand1 | 200            |   null      | 230        | 200
ocm30   | someBrand2 | 300            |   320       | null       | 300
```

(so, without rows like ocm40, ocm50 which aren't presented in first table)

*how is it possible to get only rows, presented in* `mainTable`?

so in result i will have only rows with articles: `ocm10, ocm20, ocm30` with joined data of prices?

here is fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/87df2/4/0

btw: I know, that the same structure is not a good idea... in real app tables are different, this is only a sample. And I can have more than 3 same tables: even 10 with joins etc...

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result, as formatted text (not images.)

Comment: @jarlh done, check it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to just left join the first table to the other two:

```
SELECT
    t1.article,
    t1.brand,
    t1.price AS priceMainTable,
    t2.price AS priceSecond,
    t3.price AS priceThird,
    MIN(t1.price,
        COALESCE(t2.price, t1.price),
        COALESCE(t3.price, t1.price)) AS minPrice
FROM mainTable t1
LEFT JOIN secondTable t2
    ON t1.article = t2.article
LEFT JOIN thirdTable t3
    ON t1.article = t3.article;
```

Note here that we use the scalar version of `MIN` which accepts multiple arguments.  The `COALESCE` logic is that the second and third price "defer" back to the first price should either be `NULL`.  So if, for example, both the second and third price were `NULL`, then the minimum price would be determined by the first price, which is the only reliable piece of information available.

Comment: `min(x,0)` is `0`.

Comment: @CL. I see the problem now...I very rarely using the scalar `MIN` function...easy to mess it up.